# After implementing HandlerInterceptorAdapter Flash Attributes don't work

Tags: java, spring, session, interceptor

Hi everybody I will be fast here is my **HandlerInterceptorAdapter**

```
public class PropertiesInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PropertiesInterceptor.class);

@Autowired
SessionManagerService sessionManagerService;

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    if (sessionManagerService.getSessionAttribute(request, AppProperties.USER_LOGGED.toString()) != null) {
        modelAndView.addObject(AppProperties.USER_LOGGED.toString(), sessionManagerService.getSessionAttribute(request, AppProperties.USER_LOGGED.toString()));
    }

}
}
```

As you can see its noting special. Here is some method in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user/profile/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProfile(@ModelAttribute("user") UserImpl user, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    user = userService.saveEditedUser(user);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("infoMessage", true);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", settingsService.getTranslate("user.message.editPersonalData", null, request));

    sessionManagerService.setSessionAttribute(request, AppProperties.USER_LOGGED.toString(), user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " (" + user.getUsername() + ")");

    return "redirect:/admin/user/profile";
}
```

Before adding my **HandlerInterceptorAdapter** the FlashAttributes works perfectly now I only see in top URL the property from **AppProperties.USER_LOGGED** called userLogged, any ideas why this is not working anymore ?

EDIT:

spring configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
        ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.allegroapp"/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="pl.allegroapp.interceptors.PropertiesInterceptor" autowire="constructor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="pl.allegroapp"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="transactionPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <!-- Internationalization -->
    <bean id="messageSource"

          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:/languages/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="pl"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And my spring version is **4.1.4.RELEASE**

Comment: Please add your spring version and applicationContext.xml at least configuration part.

Comment: Added all you want :-) any ideas ?

Comment: Solution answered [here (using FlashMap)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178524)